Flutter: deep link supported web adresses are disabled by default
I'm trying to get android deep links to work, however, they are disabled by default
I've hosted the assetlinks files, and they are validated by Google Play & Flutter deep link validators. I took the SHA-256 from the Play Store "App Signin" section.
I made sure to check the deep link status from the Play Store release (so prod environnement) and it's still disabled by default
AndroidManifest.xml :
        <meta-data android:name="google_analytics_deferred_deep_link_enabled" android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="mycustomscheme"  />
            <data android:scheme="http"  />
            <data android:scheme="https"  />

            <data android:host="firstadress.com" />
            <data android:host="cms.secondadress.com"  />
        </intent-filter>

Here is the app links in prod (all disabled by default, ignore the 3rd adress that comes from an earlier build)

I'd also like to add that Play Store gives me the warning
Upgrade web links to app links Add the android:autoVerify="true" attribute to intent filters and verify domain ownership" 

When i have it on my Manifest file
Any leads on how i debug this ?
